# Turbo Pascal for DOS - How to get the current timezone offset

Tags: utc, dos, timezone-offset, turbo-pascal

I need to make a modification to a legacy app written in Turbo Pascal 7 which requires me to find out the current timezone offset.  The program runs in a DOS box in a 32-bit XP environment.

Anybody know of a way of doing this?

** EDIT **

I probably should add that the reason for this question is because I want to know the UTC time , i.e. I want a way of calling a `GetSystemTime` equivalent from DOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an Exec statement in Pascal to run the DOS systeminfo command output with a pipe, then parse the resulting output using Pascal. Example...

```
c:\>systeminfo | find "Time Zone"
Time Zone:                 (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)

c:\>
```

It takes a sec on Windows 7 to get the result but it should run faster on XP.

Comment: Clever.  It's a shame it takes so long.  Pity there aren't command line options to provide a subset of the info.  I might experiment with  this.  Maybe prune the output of the command a bit further and set an environment variable, assuming I can read that in DOS too, which will be considerably faster.  The `systeminfo` command could then run only infrequently - say hourly.

Comment: You could use another DOS program besides sysinfo (something you install) or try getting the setting from the registry of Turbo Pascal supports that sort of thing.

Comment: Hmmm... @Rick, TP doesn't seem to support the registry.

Comment: Best is to migrate to Free Pascal, it is highly compatible and can access windows resources, and won't get confused by a space in a path.